# UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Yes, I have already looked at all the other posts with this error.

Here is my code: Where am I going wrong here?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)TableView:(UITableView *)myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [_myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [_cellArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: your method name is wrong ? tableView not TableView

Comment: I add my comment as answer. Please accept if that helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method name is wrong. Replace `TableView` with `tableView`. To prevent this kinds of error, once you set your datasource or delegate, you should use control + Space, so Xcode can help you by completing the correct method name.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with this method name:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)TableView:(UITableView *)myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Replace it with:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView tableView:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Tthe actual method name is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` not  `TableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`